# mySQL Update value using a max date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query, I want to be able to update the exec value to **TRUE** when my program finishes to execute a request and save it to my database to use it as a queue for when I have multiple executions, however, whenever I try with this query it gives me an error.

```
UPDATE motor 
SET exec=1 
where time=(SELECT max(time) 
            FROM motor 
            WHERE exec=0);
```

Error:

> *ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'motor' for update in FROM clause*

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because your UPDATE could be cycling.

Use this code instead of :

```
UPDATE motor 
SET exec = 1 
WHERE exec = 0 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this as two separate queries. ALso, why aren't you having your program keep track of the primary key of the "motor" it's working on in the queue and update based on that?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value you get from your SELECT statement to a variable like the following:

```
DECLARE varTime datetime;
SELECT varTime := max(time) FROM motor WHERE exec=0;
UPDATE motor SET exec=1 where time= varTime
```

I'm not too sure on the syntax as I mainly work on MS SQL Server but I know it should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Your accepted answer is correct. Is it also possible to obtain the same result with this:

```
UPDATE
  motor inner join
  (SELECT max(time) as time
   FROM motor 
   WHERE exec=0) mx on motor.time = mx.time 
SET motor.exec=1;
```

The only difference is that if there are more than one row with the same maximum value, `LIMIT 1` will update just one of those rows, while this will update all.